# How do i detect served ad dimensions

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, ads, google-dfp

I am currently using google publisher tags with DFP to serve up ads to a site that will very soon be responsive. We have one particular ad slot which can potentially serve up 2 potential widths, 728 or 960 and depending on which width gets served up I want to either render the ad above or below the nav.

So the obvious first question is whether or not this is even remotely sane and furthermore is it possible? I suspect i should probably define two distinct ad slots.

The primary question though which is probably more of an academic one is how can I detect the dimensions of an ad that has been served? I suspect the solution to this is agnostic to the ad platform since I am basically detected node insertion and then inspecting the dimensions of the container element.

I've been experimenting with the DOMNodeInserted javascript event however it seems to trigger for everything "BUT" the ads. I am confused by this unless gpt inserts the ads in a way that does not trigger this event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done something like this before... and the method I settled upon was overriding an internal DFP function (renderEnded) so that I could see what the ad was at the point it had rendered on screen...

For example to get the dimensions of the ad you could do something like the following (I've only tested this in chrome but it shouldn't be too far from being fully cross browser):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>DFP test</title>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var googletag = googletag || {};
        googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
        (function() {
            var gads = document.createElement('script');
            gads.async = true;
            gads.type = 'text/javascript';
            var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
            gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
            '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
            var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
        })();
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
            var slot1 = googletag.defineSlot('/12345678/TEST', [266, 115], 'div-gpt-ad-1340819095858-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

            slot1.oldRenderEnded = slot1.renderEnded;
            slot1.renderEnded = function(){
                window.console.log('width: '+document.getElementById('div-gpt-ad-1340819095858-0').getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.width);
                window.console.log('height: '+document.getElementById('div-gpt-ad-1340819095858-0').getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.height);
                slot1.oldRenderEnded();
            };

            googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
            googletag.enableServices();
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id='div-gpt-ad-1340819095858-0' style='width:266px; height:115px;'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            googletag.cmd.push(function() {
                googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1340819095858-0');
            });
        </script>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

That might not be quite what you are after but overriding that function should let you get to where you need to be... let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This is actually the closest solution to what i'm looking for. The next step is to consistently detect the intended width of the creative rendered inside the ad slot. For us the creative can vary between iframes, images, and flash objects. I've found that they almost always have a width param that i can read. Detecting the rendered width seems problematic if the container div is too small since the creative just gets smashed horizontally.

Comment: @Matt Cooper - Where and how did you discover the internal DFP function renderEnded? If there are other functions I can override that would be great.

Comment: @umami I found it just by looking into the googletag name space with chrome inspector. If you fire up the inspector and type googletag into the console you will see the googletag object... there are a few functions in there and if you look into the slot_manager_instance and drill down into the individual ad units you will find a whole lot of other functions...

Another repo which I found at a later date hooks the internal dfp logger and makes it possible to hook into other dfp functions as well, you might find that interesting: https://github.com/mcountis/dfp-events

Comment: @Ken's answer below is now more correct, although this was the correct answer at the time - it is also documented and supported, so hopefully won't be withdrawn in the future (whereas renderEnded could be)

Comment: Yes @MarkD you are correct... my answer is now outdated with the new changes to GPT - glad they finally released a solid way to do this!

Answer (score 13):

There's been an update to GPT which allows this to be done in a more elegant manner.
The event will tell you if a creative was returned and if so the dimensions, as well as additional information.

```
googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {
 console.log('Creative with id: ' + event.creativeId +
  ' is rendered to slot of size: ' + event.size[0] + 'x' + event.size[1]);
});
```

There is also event.isEmpty which will tell you if an actual creative was returned or not.

Comment: and an event.Size too "array, indicates size of rendered creative." https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1650154?hl=en

Comment: This should really be the selected answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem over on WiiMusic.net with Google AdSense.  What I ended up doing was detecting the size of the div containing the ad with JavaScript and then loaded the ad.  In this situation, it wasn't possible to change resolution or size of my page once loaded, so this worked.

In your situation, your page can certainly change size and what not.  I think you will have to re-load the ads at that point, if you want different ad versions to be visible depending on your responsive design.  If you are using the asynchronous ad code, this should be possible.

To sum it up, yes, this is sane and possible with JavaScript.  Your ads require JavaScript to work anyway, so this shouldn't be too much of a barrier.

Comment: In my situation I actually need to do the reverse of that. I will be adjusting the size/position of the containing div depending on the size of the served ad not the other way around. In order to do that i need to find some way to define a callback for when the ad is inserted. As I've stated I've tried the DOMNodeInserted event and also i'm experimenting with DOMSubtreeModified to detect when the ad content is inserted.

Comment: @sphoid, Forgive my ignorance, but I thought DFP ad slots could only contain one size?  How does DFP determine which size ad to serve you?  You are sizing your page differently depending on which size ad you get back?  I think the DOMNodeInserted issue is due to the iframe in which the ad is being served in.

Comment: You can define multiple ad sizes separated by commas for one slot in googletag.defineslot(). I do this mainly for the leaderboard ad slot which can serve up full page width banners as well as narrower centered banners. Some of my ads do not insert iframes, instead they generate a div dynamically and insert some script tags and sometimes object tags if the creative is flash based. I should be able to detect when those elements are inserted at least.

Answer (score 0):

So as usual I was way over thinking this. The reason I wasn't detecting a DOM change is because the ad had already been inserted by the time i was assigning event handlers. WHen loading ads synchronously I can immediately measure the dimensions of the container div and get the ad dimensions. When loading asynchronously I'm able to poll for inner html changes by storing the original html using and polling for changes and making the measurement of the container div when the change occurs. Thanks Brad for your time.

Comment: I spoke too soon. This solution only works in situations where the container div can and will resize when the creative warrants it. I have a scenario where the container div cannot resize so the creative gets smashed horizontally which is the very problem i'm trying to avoid. I guess i need a legit way to detect the dimensions of the creative.